# UI-Select2 remove option from dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ui-select2

I am using ui-select2.

I have a dropdown that has the options generated from an ng-repeat. I want to be able to click a button to remove the currently selected item from the array of items. that change is not reflection in the ui-select2 UI.

Do I have to reload ui-select2 on the element or something of that nature?

Here is a Plunker of what I want to do.

http://plnkr.co/edit/9g6zBHucyDX4nAnWQtc4?p=preview

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, until somebody comes up with a neat solution, playing a bit with your plunker has yield this:

```
$scope.items = $scope.items.slice(1, $scope.items.length);
```

Check out this forked [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/llB2gjiWNnm3zbX43HuI?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks! How would it work for deleted the item that is currently selected? I updated my post and the plunker. Thank you!